# Can't send request to Luis

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, azure-language-understanding

I started to look into luis and I decided to give it a try. I have activated luis cognitive service and I got my keys. I'm now trying to send a question to luis from python program and get any kind of response. But, whatever I do, I always get `<Response [401]>`. What am I doing wrong? My keys and subscription ID are in the config file. My code is here:

```
import configparser
import requests


config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')


headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': config['DEFAULT']['key_1'],
}

query = input('Ask LUIS: ')

params ={
    # Query parameter
    'q': query,
    # Optional request parameters, set to default values
    'timezoneOffset': '0',
    'verbose': 'false',


'spellCheck': 'false',
    'staging': 'false',
}

r = requests.get('https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/' + str(config['DEFAULT']['subscription_ID']), headers=headers, params=params)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: did you try your request in the browser? It is possible to test it in all browsers - and the response might tell you more than just "401"

Comment: Yes I've tried that but it also says that I do not have a permission and that are the keys that were generated when I created the Luis project on Azure

Comment: Is this what you get? " "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." }"

Comment: Do you use "Collaborators" - meaning do you share your LUIS app among multiple Azure accounts?

Comment: No, I created the instance and I'm the only one using it.

Comment: What if you try to use your "Starter_Key" that is present in each LUIS application by default? Does that work? If so I would suggest to use "Assign resource" button and add new key and try again.

Comment: Did you give a try to : https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c37

Comment: @rudolf_franek I cannot find the 'Starter_Key'. Where should I look for it? 
@ SandT Yes, I have tried that but it's of no use, the result is the same as a result I get from running my script

Comment: Starter_Key is locaten in every single LUIS application from its very creation in "Manage>Keys and Endpoint settings"

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/iQEW9lW) is what I see:

Comment: @Novak, did you add the subscription key into the LUIS app? If you haven't done this, you will certainly receive a 401 error. You can add (and access the starter/authoring key in your LUIS app under Manage => Keys and Endpoints.

Comment: @Novak - you created your LUIS application in portal.azure.com, correct? Did you try to access it via www.luis.ai? At this url you are able to see "Manage>Keys and Endpoint settings" as I mentioned previously.